# Space removed by preg_split

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I want to split the string by a dot followed by a space. However, `preg_split` removes the space from the matched part.

How can I keep the space?

```
preg_split('/(?<=[.])\s+/u', 'One. Two. Three.', null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

// Result: ['One.', 'Two.', 'Three.']
// Expected: ['One. ', 'Two. ', 'Three.']
```

Comment: you can use the explode function

Comment: print_r(explode(' ',$string));

Comment: @RakeshJakhar That would remove the spaces too, right?

Comment: @kerbholz - No, because it is not present in the initial string. I don't understand why the preg_split removes the space, but keeps the dot.

Comment: @RakeshJakhar - _"How can I keep the space?"_ - `explode()` will remove it and produce the same results as the OP's current code.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson you can add it again inside the variable, its looks like only last element don't have space rest have the space

Comment: @RakeshJakhar - Sure, but that can be done with the OP's current code as well. Using `explode()` instead of the current code won't change anything.

Comment: Can there be more than one space? if so, do you want to keep them all?

Comment: @Nick - yes, it should keep all of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could turn the positive lookahead into a match and then use `\K` to  forget what was matched. Also, to match one or more whitespaces, use `\s+`.

```
\.\s+\K
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/45ruJO/1)

```
var_dump(preg_split('/\.\s+\K/', 'One. Two. Three.', null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));
```

Result

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "One. "
  [1]=>
  string(5) "Two. "
  [2]=>
  string(6) "Three."
}
```

Comment: I was going to go with this solution but OP says in the comments that there can be more than one space and if there are he wants to capture them all.

Comment: @Nick Agreed, I have removed the first option and turned into making use of `\K`

Answer (score 2):

You can use preg_match_all and match anything then dot and an optional space

```
preg_match_all("/(.*?\.\s*)/", 'One. Two. Three.',$m);
```

Results:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "One. "
    [1]=>
    string(5) "Two. "
    [2]=>
    string(6) "Three."
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "One. "
    [1]=>
    string(5) "Two. "
    [2]=>
    string(6) "Three."
  }
}
```

https://3v4l.org/ZFV9t

Comment: The regex would probably be more efficient if you use `[^.]*` rather than `.*?`

Comment: @Nick maybe it is. I tried it on 3v4l and it's actually slower. But that isn't the full truth though.

Comment: Regex101 suggests 30 steps for `.*?` and 18 for `[^.]*`. https://regex101.com/r/uCFCZU/1

Comment: Anyway, just being picky. This is the best way to solve OPs problem.

Comment: Why `'One.Two.Three'` returns `['One', 'Two', 'Three']` and not the initial string? There is no space between the words.

Comment: @Bacchus `\s*` needs to be changed to `\s+` in the regex

Answer (score 0):

As per your expected result.

```
$string = 'One. Two. Three.';

$split = preg_split("/(\w+\W+)/", $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE|PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
var_dump($split);
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.